# compare two arrays using the array_diff_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

I want to compare `$image = $row['colum1 ']` to `$file = readdir($dh)` however it doesnt seem to be working with `$compare = array_diff_assoc($image, $uploads);` any ideas?

```
<?php
//pulling images from mysql colum1
require 'databaseConnection.php'
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT column1 FROM table1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $image = $row ['colum1'] . "<br/>";
}

//pulling pictures from specific path
$dir = "application/uploads";
if(is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $uploads = $file . "<br>";
       }
    }
}

//attempting to compare $image to $upload
$compare = array_diff_assoc($image, $uploads);
print_r($compare);
```

Comment: Can you show us what the result of `$compare` is in this case and what you expected it to be? Because it's not obvious what you want here. You're overwriting the value of `$image` and `$uploads` in every iteration of those loops. So not sure why `array_diff_assoc` is even being used here.

Comment: To be clear, `readdir()` returns a string, while `mysqli_fetch_array()` should returns an array. Why are expecting this comparison to be sane?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you actually want here is `array_diff()` and not `array_diff_assoc()`, since the latter compares both **keys** and **values**, while the former is only concerned with **values**. I can't imagine why keys are relevant to your use case here.

You're making a few mistakes in that you're `readdir()` loop simply stores a string in the variable `$uploads` (*your're overwriting the value with every iteration of the loop*), and `$images` (*also being overwritten with every iteration*) would store an array of columns from the given row of that iteration.

What you *probably* meant to do was get an array of just the one column in your table that stores the file names and compare it to an array of the filenames on disk.

What's important to remember when using `arary_diff()` is that order matters, because the result is a list of values in the first array that are not present in any of the other arrays. Meaning you have to ask yourself do you want to know which files in the database are not on disk or do you want to know which files on disk are not in the database?

Here's a [short gist on how to visualize the different array operations in PHP](https://gist.github.com/srgoogleguy/214db6389024e9125bcb1f43804cc2e4).

> ```
> $array1 = [
>     "red",
>     2,
>     "green",
>     "blue",
> ];
>
> $array2 = [
>     "orange",
>     "green",
>     "blue",
>     "red",
> ];
>
> $diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);
>
> var_dump($diff);
> ```
>
> [image: array_diff]

So let's assume that in your code you do this:

```
<?php
//pulling images from mysql colum1
require 'databaseConnection.php'
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT column1 FROM table1");

$images = []; // store a list of images from the database

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $images[] = $row['colum1'];
}

//pulling pictures from specific path
$dir = "application/uploads";

$uploads = []; // store a list of files on disk

if(is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $uploads[] = $file;
       }
    }
}

//attempting to compare $image to $upload
$compare = array_diff($images, $uploads);
print_r($compare);
```

If the result of `$images` and `$uploads` were as follows:

```
$images  = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpg"];
$uploads = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg"];
```

Then the result of `$compare` should be `["c.jpg"]` as it's the only value present in `$images` that is not present in `$uploads`.